# What values should I use for Bond Yield in Grahams Valuation outside the US

Tags: stock-analysis, australia

Total newbie here, please be gentle.   I'm an Australian, going through the various intrinsic valuation models trying to wrap my head around what they mean and currently looking at Graham's Valuation:

[image]

Graham uses US AAA corporate bond yields for Yavg and Ycurrent.   My questions are:

1. Surely US corporate bond yields would not be applicable to share valuation outside of the US?
2. If so, what should I be using for Yavg and Ycurrent in Australia?

(Caveats: I'm not going to be using these valuations directly to buy shares.  I know this valuation is considered out of date these days. My goal here is to understand the various thought processes for valuing companies.)

Comment: I'm going to use iShares Core Corporate Bond ETF (ASX: ICOR) in the meantime as an estimate.. this may be crazy though.